# self-calling initializer for UI-graphic elements

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have multiple UIViews, UIButtons etc. and would like to execute some specific code for each when i first use them.

For example for my `UIButton *title`, when i call `title.frame` for the first time, i would like first to call a setter that will verify that my button isn't nill and if it is then alloc and init my button, set my title to @"TITLE" etc.

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing you are talking about lazy initialization but that will require you to use the accessor method `self.title.frame` instead of `title.frame`. You can implement the getter method like this.

```
- (UIButton *)title {
    if ( !title ) {
        // Allocate the button
        // Set the button title
    }
    return title;
}
```

Comment: To further clarify why this call `self.title.frame` will work like @Deepak suggests and possibly demystify a bit further. It is because this call will be compiled to `[[self title] frame];`. The same for if you are setting the frame like this `self.title.frame = newFrame;` will compile to `[[self title] setFrame:newFrame];` Both times the getter is being called first so you can lazily initialize.